# Find the least value of $a$ for which the limit $(x-2)^{0.5}$ as $x$ approaches $a$ exists

Tags: calculus

Find the least value of a for which the limit $(x-2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ as $x$ approaches $a$ exists.
The answer to this question is given as $2$.But if $x$ approaches $2$ from the left, then $(x-2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ cannot be calculated at such values of $x$. More so, this results in a complex number,how can we compare a real no.(when $x$ approaches $2$ from the right) with a complex one?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Answer (score 1):

When $x$ approaches $2$, the left hand neighborhood is not in the **Domain** of the function. Hence, for calculation of the limit, only the right hand neighborhood is taken into account.

Comment: That means the limit does not exist?

Comment: In order that the limit exists, both the right hand and the left hand should be equal, but here we cannot proceed with the left hand side.